# how do i move the buy option to the right side?

Tags: react-native

i'm new to react-native and mobile application. I'm trying to build a basic shopping app. i have items to the left and the buy option to the right but the "buy" option falls just below the items list

i tried using AlignItems,justifyContent.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, Button, ScrollView, StyleSheet, AppRegistry, Text, View }
  from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  red: {
    color: 'red',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    margin: 0,
  },
  alternativeLayoutButtonContainer: {
    margin: 20,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
});




class Greeting extends Component {

  _onPressButton() {
    Alert.alert('Sorry you have no credit!')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.alternativeLayoutButtonContainer}>
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-start', height: 75 }}>
          <Text style={styles.red}>{this.props.name}</Text>

          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="BUY"
          />
        </View>
      </View>


    );

  }
}

export default class LotsOfGreetings extends Component {



  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{
          alignItems: 'flex-start', top: 0, flex: 2,
          backgroundColor: 'black'
        }}>

          <Greeting name='Shoe- 900' />
          <Greeting name='Football Studs - 700' />
          <Greeting name='Football - 600' />
          <Greeting name='Jersey - 450' />
          <Greeting name='Stockings - 200' />
          <Greeting name='Cones - 50' />
          <Greeting name='Whistle - 80' />
          <Greeting name='Shin Pads - 250' />
          <Greeting name='GoalKeeper gloves - 900' />
          <Greeting name='Nets - 1500' />

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => LotsOfGreetings);
```

i would like the buy option to be aligned straight to the items list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the text and the button inside a flex container that will be responsible for defining their alignment.

Your Greeting component:

```js
class Greeting extends Component {

  _onPressButton() {
    Alert.alert('Sorry you have no credit!')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="BUY"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );

  }
}
```

Now the style:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rowContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 75,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row', // children will be on the same line
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
   flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    flex: 2, // Text takes twice more space than button container
    color: 'red',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```